Exception thrown: read access violation.Unable to read memory
My English is not very good, I'm sorry.I'm a beginner and want to do a problem with Ternary search tree. The problem occurs during the insertion of the node,VS throws an exception in insert_BiTreeNode: Read access violation.  0xcdcdcdcd {key=??? left=??? mid=??? ...}
I don't know how to fix it.
Below is my code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int key;
    struct BiTNode *left;
    struct BiTNode *mid;
    struct BiTNode *right;
}BiTNode, *BiTree;

int Max(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a >= b && a >= c)
        return a;
    else if (c >= a && c >= b)
        return c;
    else if (b >= a && b >= c)
        return b;
}

BiTree create_BiTreeNode(int key) {
    BiTNode* node = (BiTNode*)malloc(sizeof(BiTNode));
    node->key = key;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}

BiTree insert_BiTreeNode(BiTNode* root, int key) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = create_BiTreeNode(key);
        return root;
    }
    if (key < root->key - 500) {
        root->left = insert_BiTreeNode(root->left, key);
    }
    else if (key > root->key + 500) {
        root->right = insert_BiTreeNode(root->right, key);
    }
    else {
        root->mid = insert_BiTreeNode(root->mid, key);
    }
    return root;
}

int TreeHeight(BiTNode* root)
{
    if (root == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL && root->mid == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }
    return Max(TreeHeight(root->left), TreeHeight(root->right), TreeHeight(root->mid)) + 1;
}

int main(){
    BiTNode* root = NULL;

    int N;
    scanf_s("%d", &N);
    int* arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)* N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf_s("%d", &arr[i]);
        root = insert_BiTreeNode(root, arr[i]);
    }
    int res = TreeHeight(root);
    printf("%d", res);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}



Did you ignore the compiler warnings? If you didn't get any warnings it's time to increase the compilers warning level

What is the exact input that results in a crash?

0xcdcdcdcd indicates that you are using some uninitialized variable. You should run your program in a debugger and step through the relevant code. Then inspect involved variables to identify which does not hold expected values.

Unrelated: Your arr in main is rather pointless. You can replace that allocated array by a single int variable as you don't use any value again after adding it to the tree.

typedef struct { --> typedef struct BiTNode {

else if (b >= a && b >= c) --> return b;

Thank you for your answer. After checking, I found that I forgot to add the mid node in create_BiTreeNode.I've also changed the input method in the main function.

Your code is initially incorrect and shall not be compiled.
In this declaration
typedef struct {
    int key;
    struct BiTNode *left;
    struct BiTNode *mid;
    struct BiTNode *right;
}BiTNode, *BiTree;

there are declared two different structures. The first one is an unnamed complete structure with the alias name BiTNode and the second one is an incomplete structure with the tag name BiTNode  as for example in this line
    struct BiTNode *left;

So the compiler will issue an error that you are using incompatible pointers or incomplete types if you are compiling your program as a C program or that there is a redefinition of the name BiTNode if you are compiling your program as a C++ program.
You should declare the structure like
typedef struct BiTNode {
    int key;
    struct BiTNode *left;
    struct BiTNode *mid;
    struct BiTNode *right;
}BiTNode, *BiTree;

Within the function create_BiTreeNode not all data members are initialized of the created node.
And the function Max can be written simpler as for example
int Max(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a >= b && a >= c)
        return a;
    else if ( c >= b)
        return c;
    else
        return b;
}

